# Reducing the size of Common Lisp binary

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl

The SBCL created stumpwm is greater than 40 MB, which is too big just for a Window Manager. The C produced DWM is about 30K.

We donot need a complete CL environment, How can i make stumpwm smaller ?

Sincerely !

Comment: There are very capable WM out there that don't require an entire environment, like xmonad (you need GHC to compile it). The reason you would pick stumpwm would be that you would also use the running Lisp image for other purposes, not just the WM. Anyway, 40MB is not that much, you shouldn't worry about it, otherwise you should also worry of having a big X server running for just "painting" over the screen, incredibly giant web browsers, enormous media players, etc.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11036070/lisp-binary-size

Comment: thanks for all your answers. The stumpwm is just an example. What i really want to know is whether or not we can produce executable without CL environment as haskell does ?

Comment: For all intent and purposes, you could consider the CL image as the JVM of Java.

Comment: If the customer has JRE installed, then we can just release our application which is maybe a jar file without JVM boundled.  How about CL ?

Comment: You can release your application as a bundle without caring about anything else, provided the customer platform supports your CL implementation. Sure, with Java you only include some JARs and that maybe all. But it's not that bad to include the entire CL image (it's only a couple MB in this age of GB). Two different approaches. Also, I've seen a lot of Java applications that also include their own JVM just in case the customer doesn't have it, or the version installed is incompatible with the one used by the application,specially with older JVM. In the end of the day, it doesn't matter at all.

Comment: (continued) IMO, smaller doesn't make it better, just smaller. Nobody cares how small it is on disk (unless it's insanely huge). Having the entire CL environment grants you access to the compiler, for doing highly advanced stuff on runtime. But commercial implementations give you the choice to strip the compiler from the image when distributing. It may shave a couple MB, but I don't think that's the reason for it

Comment: try [ECL](http://ecls.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: WhiteCat, You make me understand CL more, thanks!

Comment: ECL cannot run stumpwm normally

Comment: @WhiteCat xmonad compiles to ~/.xmonad/xmonad-x86_64-linux (in my case at least) which is ~5MB, so it looks like it packs quite a lot there.

Comment: @steadyrain sure but it requires GHC plus libraries installed. Add that to your 5MB binary and you get the real size of xmonad plus dependencies. IMNSHO, binary size doesn't matter anymore, it's just a perception we get on how optimized a piece of software appears to be. Anyway, I'm sure compiled FASL is not much worse in MBs of disk usage.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lisp binary size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11036070/lisp-binary-size)

Answer (score 8):

SBCL supports compressed core images since 1.0.52. See http://xach.livejournal.com/295584.html for details.